# Problem Invoking operations in a Windows Form which triggers async API calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-forms-designer

I have a console application which either invokes a class and runs as a console application or triggers a windows form. The windows form inturn sends parameters and invokes the same operation done otherwise.

Invocation point:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(AppSettingsHelper.GetValue<bool>("EnableWindowsForm"))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("EnableWindowsForm is set to true - Running Windows form");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1(0));

            //First Time
            var form = new ReportGeneratorForm();
            Application.Run(form);

        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("EnableWindowsForm is set to false - Running direct program in console");
            PortalMonitoring monitoring = new PortalMonitoring();
            monitoring.Process();
        }
    }
```

Now In Click of Button the Same Class is triggered

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    PortalMonitoring monitoring = new PortalMonitoring();
    monitoring.Process(DateTime.Now); //Date as paramater- Default is null
}
```

If i trigger the console app, it works well.
However if i click the button the code is stuck at point of async web api call -below code

```
int reportID = GetReportIDAsync().Result;



 private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> GetReportIDAsync()
        {
            var reportName = "Portal name";
            var reportID = await ops.GetReportId(reportName);

            LogAndWriteToConsole("Report ID Feched : " + reportID.ToString());
            return reportID;
        }
```

Kindly help me here, i think windows form doesnt seem to allow multi threads by defauly. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the complete path from `monitoring.Process()` to `GetReportIDAsync()` but it needs to be async/await all the way.

The top level should look like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // probably add a try/catch here
    PortalMonitoring monitoring = new PortalMonitoring();
    await monitoring.Process(DateTime.Now); //Date as paramater- Default is null
}
```

Your no-winforms branch shoud then use `monitoring.Process().Wait()`